# MacBook Air shuts down on fully charged, healthy battery

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I have a MacBook Air 13" High Sierra, early 2015.  The computer is only a year old. Battery life is good, amperage good, holding a charge.  The problem is, the very instant I unplug the Magsafe adapter it shuts down. Goes black.  Dead.  I've reset the SMC to no avail.  I'm attaching images to show that the battery is indeed fine. Before I take this to the Apple store I thought I would check in with this bright, enlightened community.

[image: screen shot1]

[image: screen shot2]

Comment: When it does shut down, can you power it back on without the MagSafe adaptor plugged in?

Answer (score 0):

I have a MacBook Pro 2009 with the exact same problem. I followed many internet threads. None of the advices worked, even after replacing the battery with a new one. Finally I changed the power setting to "better battery life" in the system preferences and the problem went away.  Previously I had it on "higher performance"